# Using render_block only on Gutenberg blocks which aren't nested

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I want to add a wrapper div to Gutenberg blocks so I can do things like full width images and other custom ACF blocks. I found this on the WP documentation:

```
function block_wrap_filter( $block_content, $block ) {
    if ( empty( trim( $block_content ) ) ) {
        return $block_content;
    }
    $blockid = $block['id'];
    echo $blockid;
    return sprintf(
        '<section class="outer-%1$s"><div class="inner">%2$s</div></section>',
        sanitize_title( $block['blockName'] ),
        $block_content
    );
}
add_filter( 'render_block', 'block_wrap_filter', 10, 2 );
```

This works great except for the fact that it will apply the wrappers to nested blocks. Is there anyway to filter it so it doesn't apply to blocks that are within other blocks?

I've looked to see if there's any hooks or if the $block var lists itself as a child or anything but can't see anything I can make use of there.

I thought maybe if I could get the ID of the block and then see if the child has a related ID, then maybe I could use some sort of php if statement to wrap the filter. But I haven't been able to get $block to give an ID.

Comment: Was this ever resolved?